# expected expression before 'struct' in list_for_each tutorial

Tags: pointers, struct, doubly-linked-list

I am getting following error  `expected expression before 'struct'`  for the line

`struct my_obj *obj = list_entry(i, struct my_obj, node);`

in the bottom portion of the code below:

```
struct my_container {
    struct list_head list;
    int some_member;
    /* etc. */
};

struct my_obj {
    struct list_head node;
    int some_member;
    /* etc. */
};

void func() {
    struct my_container container;
    struct my_obj obj1, obj2;
    struct list_head *i;

    /* INIT_LIST_HEAD(&container.list); */
    container.list.next = &container.list;
    container.list.prev = &container.list;

    /* list_add_tail(&obj1.node); */
    container.list.prev = &obj1.node;
    obj1.node.next = &container.list;
    obj1.node.prev = &container.list;
    container.list.next = &obj1.node;

    /* list_add_tail(&obj2.node); */
    container.list.prev = &obj2.node;
    obj2.node.next = &container.list;
    obj2.node.prev = &obj1.node;
    obj1.node.next = &obj2.node;

    /* list_for_each(i, &container.list) { */
    for (i = container.list.next; i != &container.list; i = i->next) {
        struct my_obj *obj = list_entry(i, struct my_obj, node);
        /* do stuff */
    }

}
```

Would you please advise what does it want before `struct` in the portion
`list_entry(i, struct my_obj, node);`

Comment: Can you post the *full* error message please.

Comment: Remember to always [tag your question with the language you are using](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) -- [tag:c] in this case. The language tag is the most important tag to use when asking questions; without it, the question is more difficult to find (for those answering & for future viewers).

Comment: This is the error message : ```main.c:41:44: error: expected expression before ‘struct’
         struct my_obj *obj = list_entry(i, struct my_obj, node); ```

Comment: You can [edit] your question at any time, to fix mistakes, add clarification, etc rather than adding followup comments. Most importantly, **do not post entire blocks of code/errors in the comments** -- it can't be read or understood easily. It needs to be [correctly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Suppress 'struct' in the function parameters :

```
struct my_obj *obj = list_entry(i, struct my_obj, node);
```

->

```
struct my_obj *obj = list_entry(i, my_obj, node);
```

Comment: What is the definition of list_entry ? Is it a fonction? A macro ?